# NodeJs: how to retrieve AWS secret

Tags: node.js, aws-secrets-manager, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have several secret keys in AWS that I'd like to use in my NodeJs code, but I always get 'undefined' and nothing else.

I have this file "secret.ts" :

```html
// Create a Secrets Manager client
export class AWS_Secret {
    constructor() {
        // this is intentional
    }

    public RecupSecret = async (SecretName) => {
        let result:any;
        let result2: string;
        result = await this.GetSecret(SecretName);
        result2 = result.toString();

        return (result2);
     }
     
     public GetSecret = (SecretName) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
            region = "eu-west-1",
            secretName = SecretName,
            secret,
            decodedBinarySecret;

            var client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
                region: region
            });
            
            client.getSecretValue({SecretId: secretName}, function(err, data) {
                // console.log(err);
                if (err) {
                    if (err.code === 'DecryptionFailureException')
                        // Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
                        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                        // throw err;
                        // reject(err);
                        console.log(err);
                    else if (err.code === 'InternalServiceErrorException')
                        // An error occurred on the server side.
                        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                        // throw err;
                        console.log(err);
                    else if (err.code === 'InvalidParameterException')
                        // You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
                        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                        // throw err;
                        console.log(err);
                    else if (err.code === 'InvalidRequestException')
                        // You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
                        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                        // throw err;
                        console.log(err);
                    else if (err.code === 'ResourceNotFoundException')
                        // We can't find the resource that you asked for.
                        // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                        // throw err;
                        console.log(err);
                    reject(err);                
                } else {
                    // Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
                    // Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
                    if ('SecretString' in data) {
                        secret = data.SecretString;
                     // console.log('secret1', secret);
                        resolve(secret);
                    } else {
                        let buff = new Buffer(data.SecretBinary, 'base64');
                        decodedBinarySecret = buff.toString('ascii');
                        // console.log('secret2', decodedBinarySecret);
                        resolve(decodedBinarySecret);
                    }
                }
                 console.log(secret);
                // console.log(decodedBinarySecret)
                
                // Your code goes here.
                /*
                if (err !== '') {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(result);
                }
                */
            })
        })
    }
}
```

And this one 'config.ts' where I want to retrieve my AWS secrets in an async function and then insert them in my configs:

```html
import { AWS_Secret } from './tools/secret/secret';

export class Config {
...
    public DatadogAPIKey: any;
    public SnowflakeKey: any;
    public SQLKey: any;
    public aws_secret: AWS_Secret;
    public config: any;
...

    constructor() {
        this.aws_secret = new AWS_Secret();
...
    }

    public async init() {
        this.DatadogAPIKey = await this.aws_secret.RecupSecret('x-datadog-api-key');
        this.SnowflakeKey = await this.aws_secret.RecupSecret('x-snowflake-x');
        this.SQLKey = await  this.aws_secret.RecupSecret('x-sql-x');
    }

 
    public readConfigJSON = (): Promise <any> => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.config = '{"DEV"'+
            ':{"sqlx":{"user":"user1","password":"'+this.SQLKey+'","server":"xxxx","database":"xxxx"},'+
            '"snowflake":{"account":"xxxx","username":"user1","password":"'+this.SnowflakeKey+'","region":"eu-west-1","authenticator":"SNOWFLAKE","clientSessionKeepAlive":true,"warehouse":"xxxx","database":"xxxx","schema":"PUBLIC"}}'

            console.log(this.config);
                try {
                    this.res = JSON.parse(this.config);
                    resolve(this.res);
                } catch (ex) {
                    reject(ex);
                }
            
        });
    }
```

The problem here is that I always get "undefined" for my passwords instead of getting the secrets from AWS.

How can I do this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the init method of the Config class, you call the RecupSecret method of aws_secret to retrieve secrets. This method internally calls the GetSecret method, which makes asynchronous AWS SDK calls.The init method continues executing while the asynchronous AWS SDK calls are being made, and the DatadogAPIKey, SnowflakeKey, and SQLKey properties are assigned undefined since the secrets haven't been retrieved yet. Later in the readConfigJSON method, you're trying to use this.SQLKey and this.SnowflakeKey, which are possibly still undefined at that point.

You can try making readConfigJSON method async and await the init method before using the secret values. Give something like this a try and see if it works (This is just an idea, please find the best approach that suits your needs),

```js
public async readConfigJSON(): Promise<any> {
 await this.init(); // Wait for secrets to be retrieved

 this.config = {
     DEV: {
         sqlx: {
             user: 'user1',
             password: this.SQLKey,
             server: 'xxxx',
             database: 'xxxx'
         },
         snowflake: {
             account: 'xxxx',
             username: 'user1',
             password: this.SnowflakeKey,
             region: 'eu-west-1',
             authenticator: 'SNOWFLAKE',
             clientSessionKeepAlive: true,
             warehouse: 'xxxx',
             database: 'xxxx',
             schema: 'PUBLIC'
         }
     }
 };

 return this.config;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! It's exactly what I was missing <3